# How do I GROUP the results of a query that is already grouped?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a query:

```
SELECT

CONVERT(varchar(7),SUBMITDATE, 120) as 'Month'

,CASE WHEN ReportType = '1' THEN (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed))) END as 'Report1Avg'
,CASE WHEN ReportType = '2' THEN (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed))) END as 'Report2Avg'
,CASE WHEN ReportType = '3' THEN (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed))) END as 'Report3Avg'
,CASE WHEN ReportType = '4' THEN (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed))) END as 'Report4Avg'
,CASE WHEN ReportType = '5' THEN (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed))) END as 'Report5Avg'

FROM Table1

    WHERE STATUS = 'Closed'

GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(7),SUBMITDATE, 120), ReportType
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(7),SUBMITDATE, 120)
```

Which produces the following result:

[image: query results]

My question is: How do I consolidate the results of each month in one row?
ex. for '2015-06', I have 3 rows of results.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `avg` around the `case` expression. Also use `else 0` to avoid null values.

```
SELECT
CONVERT(varchar(7),SUBMITDATE, 120) as 'Month'
,AVG(CASE WHEN ReportType = '1' THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed) ELSE 0 END) as 'Report1Avg'
,AVG(CASE WHEN ReportType = '2' THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed) ELSE 0 END) as 'Report2Avg'
,AVG(CASE WHEN ReportType = '3' THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed) ELSE 0 END) as 'Report3Avg'
,AVG(CASE WHEN ReportType = '4' THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed) ELSE 0 END) as 'Report4Avg'
,AVG(CASE WHEN ReportType = '5' THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,SUBMITDATE,DateClosed) ELSE 0 END) as 'Report5Avg'
FROM Table1
WHERE STATUS = 'Closed'
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(7),SUBMITDATE, 120)
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(7),SUBMITDATE, 120)
```

Comment: Using the AVG around the CASE expression does not change the results.

Comment: did you observe that `reporttype` was removed from `group by`

Comment: that was it.  my mistake.  It worked!!  You are da man vkp!! =D  Thanks so much!